# One of my components isn't loading with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a problem with loading a dynamically inserted component with React Router.
I have a main menu in this component that takes routes from its props and create NavLinks for them

```
class SideNav extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="sidenav">
          {
            Object.entries(this.props.routes).map((route, index) => {
              return <NavLink key={index} exact to={route[1].path} className="link">{route[1].title}</NavLink>
            })
          }
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default SideNav;
```

I also have HomeFrame component that looks like the following

```
class homeframe extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homeframe">
        <TopNav links={this.props.links} />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={ContentFrame} />
          <Route path="/test" exact component={TestingComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default homeframe;
```

The TopNav Component renders NavLinks as it acts as a submenu

```
class TopNav extends Component {

  render() {
    const links = this.props.links;
    return (
      <nav className="topnav navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          {
           links.map(route => {
            return(
             <li className="nav-item" key={route.id}>
              <NavLink exact to={route.path} className="navlink nav-link">
                {route.title}
              </NavLink>
             </li>
            )
           })
          }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default TopNav;
```

And finally in my App.js i have

```
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <div className="App">
              <SideNav routes={routes} />    
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact render={props => (<HomeFrame links={routes.a.submenu} {...props} /> )} />
                <Route path="/stat" exact render={props => (<StatFrame links={routes.b.submenu} {...props} /> )} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

assuming that all of my imports are done correctly, when my submenu renders, only my first Navlink works, if I click on the second or third, my route fails to load the component that i need. 
here's a snap
[image]

anything i am missing?
thanks

Comment: Any error show up on console? or maybe recheck link of `Test Component` should be exactly `/test` not `/test/any-route`

Comment: @vedsmith92 it is exactly `/test` and no errors in console.